# wp_insert_post() succesfully create the post but it can't be queried

Tags: php, wordpress

The posts are beeing created by the following code:

```
 $post_args = array(
    'post_title'    => $title,
    'post_type'     => 'calendar', // my post type
    'post_content'  => $content,
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_date'     => date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', time() ),
    'post_author'   => get_current_user_id(),
);

$ID = wp_insert_post($post_args);
```

The post is created, I can check it on wordpress admin and all the fields are ok. However, **the page with the query for those posts shows no posts. It only starts showing on the query if I update it on the admin, **.

I've tested a lot of methods, tried creating it as normal post and then changing it to the custom type, removed all the other parts of my function, leaving only this one I posted, but so far no good.

I even added new args that aren't necessary at all, changing my args to the following:

```
$post_args = array(
    'post_title'    => $title,
    'post_name'     => $title,
    'post_type'     => 'calendar', // my post type
    'post_content'  => $content,
    'post_excerpt'  => $content,
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_date'     => date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', time() ),
    'post_author'   => get_current_user_id(),
);
```

But no success. What could it be?

**The query page code:**

```
$args = array(
    'num'      => -1,
    'user'     => $clienteId,
    'status'   => array( 'producao', 'aguardando', 'ajuste', 'reprovado')
);

// a custom function I've built for my system, it requires and returns the document with the wp query args
$calendar = obter_query('manage', 'calendar', 'iniciar', $args);

if ($calendar->have_posts()) : while ($calendar->have_posts()) : $calendar->the_post();  

    require get_stylesheet_directory() . '/template-parts/manage/sessions/calendar.php';
```

**The Query args code:**

```
$queryargs = array(
    'post_type'       => 'calendar',
    'order'           => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page'  => $args['num'],

    'post_status' => array(
        'publish', 
        'future'
    ),

    // ACF custom meta fields
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',

        array(
            'key'       => 'client', 
            'value'     => $args['user'],
            'compare'   => '=',
        ),

        array(
            'key'       => 'status',
            'value'     => $args['status'],
            'compare'   => 'IN',
        ),
    ),
);
```

**The obter_query() function code**

```
function obter_query($local, $file, $action, $args = null){

    require get_stylesheet_directory() . '/inc/querys/' . $local . '/' . $file . '.php';

    // If action == 'iniciar', it creates the WP_Query()
    if ($action == 'iniciar'){
        return new WP_Query($queryargs);
    }

    // else, only return the args
    return $queryargs;
}
```

**Just remindering you guys that when I post a new calendar on the wordpress admin the query shows it normally. It also shows if I update a code created calendar on the admin.**

Comment: The more you add the less you'll find. Also time changes.

Comment: "the page with the query for those posts shows no posts" - do you happen to have an object cache installed? On thing you could check from the WP CLI is running `wp cache flush` to see if it shows up in your other query

Comment: Hi @Lucas M. Falbo. *...the page with the query for those posts* sounds like the problem could be the **query** itself. Are you able to post that query in your question?

Comment: I don't have a cache plugin activaded. It is installed, but deactivated. I tried activating it and clearing the cache, but still doens't work. I'm answering the question with the page query code.

Comment: Is your custom post_type `calendar` or `calendario`?  (Either of those will collide with other  code in the plugin / template ecosystem, so be careful.)  And, my next troubleshooting step would be inspecting `obter_query()`'s code.

Comment: Actually 'calendario'. I translated to calendar only to show the example code here in english. But on my system is all 'calendario'.

I've added the obter_query() function code as requested.

Comment: I'm seeing you insert a new post, but not adding any ACF fields which is done via `update_field`. Your query is then making a `meta` query with and `AND` requiring those ACF field which aren't set. If you have any "defaults" in ACF, those are UI defaults, not database defaults.

Comment: @LucasM.Falbo. The `obter_query()` function has this for its return types: **WP_Query|array**. When `$calendar` is assigned to the return value of `obter_query()`, it accesses the method `->have_posts()`. But if `$calendar` receives an **array** (and not *WP_Query*), the call to `->have_posts()` is invalid. Is this the case?

Comment: @kofeigen yes, if i set the parameter $action as 'iniciar', wich means start, the function returns the WP_Query data, instead of the array arguments. But what I do with it it's not up to the function. So I'm only checking if ( $calendar->have_posts()) because I set the $action to start so I know the variable is returning the query.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I actually create the ACF fields, there's code for it. I choosed not to post the code here to make the question more readable and also because its no part of the bug. WIth or without it the post is not queried on the front end when created by function.

Comment: @LucasM.Falbo Chris Haas's idea sounds reasonable. You could test `$queryargs` without the meta_query to confirm that it is not the problem.

Comment: “I chose not to post the code here to make the question more readable” - although that is understandable, you have posted what is effectively an SQL `INSERT` command followed by a `SELECT` with a `WHERE` clause, the contents of which aren’t in the initial `INSERT`, so that matters. It could be ACF field names vs keys, for instance.

Comment: @kofeigen I have tested with and without the metafield keys, creating the post and using update_field() to insert the ACF fields meta data and also creating without update_field(), keeping the ACF fields empty. The bug happens anyway, so that is not the problem.

Comment: And also, I have checked on the php admin database for the post meta fields of both wp admin and code created posts to check if there any diferences. Nothing.. All the same, I'm losing my mind to this

Comment: You guys were right, the problem was indeed a ACF field.

Comment: @Lucas M. Falbo. Glad you found the solution. Perhaps you could invite Chris Haas to post his comment as an answer, and you could mark his answer as accepted? This will help those who find your question in search results. They will see that a correct answer is available. Presently, no one would know an answer was found without reading all the text. This also shows why Stack Overflow encourages posting the text of your code when asking questions or even creating a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Of course. @ChrisHaas i'm gonna wait for your answer to accept it. Again, thank you very much for all the help.

Comment: @LucasM.Falbo, since you've already done the work, and I won't have time to write anything of substance for a while, I'm 100% fine with just keeping your answer. It also includes things which are specific to your situation that only you'd know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, that is embarrassing.

The problem all the time was that I was not setting the ACF field 'status' when creating the post, and the acf meta key 'status' is used on the query args. I discovered that when I removed that argument the post starts showing.

I didn't notice my code wasn't setting the status because when I opened the post on wp admin the status was there, defined, but that happened because this field has default option. So by opening the post and updating, acf was setting the standard status and allowing my query to find this post.

Thank you very much for everyone who commented and helped me to find the issue.

I'm going to put here the original part of the code that created the post and the part that was missing:

Original code responsible for programmatically creating posts:

```
// Arguments
$post_args = array(
    'post_title'    => $titulo,
    'post_type'     => 'calendario', 
    'post_content'  => $conteudo,
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_date'     => date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', time() ),
    'post_author'   => get_current_user_id(),
);


// Create the post and gets the new post ID
$ID = wp_insert_post($post_args);

// Insert some meta data, respectively to the calendar owner, calendar month and year
update_field( 'field_6457d4d1863bc', $clienteID, $ID );
update_field( 'field_6457d4d1863fc', $data_mes, $ID );
update_field( 'field_6457d4d18643a', $data_ano, $ID );
```

As you can see, its missing the update of one acf meta field. The fix was achieved by adding the code below to the function:

```
update_field( 'field_6457d4d186475', 'production', $ID);
```